# Exe file from scheduled task returns code '2147516556'

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, exe, scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a job to run an .exe file with Windows 10 Task Scheduler, but it results in return code 2147516556. My .exe file file is on remote location (absolute path: C:\DatiEsp\Rilascio\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win10-x64\Resources\Templates\SafePlus_Mailer.exe).

If I run the .exe with command prompt then it works fine.

[image]

How can I fix this error?